# Declaring variable in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have added the following code to my script:

```pascal
[Code]
function IsSomeAppInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\SomeApp\Some.dll'));
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
   Boolean bIsInstalled := IsSomeAppInstalled();
   MsgBox('IsSomeAppInstalled: ' + IntToStr(Integer(bIsInstalled)),
     mbInformation, MB_OK);
   Result := true;
end;
```

The line

```
Boolean bIsInstalled := IsSomeAppInstalled();
```

raises the error

> Internal error (20)

What might be the error here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pascal (Script) you [declare variables using `var` keyword](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Variable) before the actual code:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  bIsInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  bIsInstalled := IsSomeAppInstalled();
  MsgBox('IsSomeAppInstalled: ' + IntToStr(Integer(bIsInstalled)),
    mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := true;
end;
```